# Using variable to display a page with a different stylesheet

Tags: css, urls

Is it possible to implement a different stylesheet for a page using a url variable, for example

**Normal URL: www.example.com/page**

Would use the normal stylesheet

**Alternative URL: www.example.com/page?=alt**

Would use an alternative stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the url is `www.example.com/page?style=alt`, you can conditionally check the presence of `$_GET['style']` when you're including your styles. Add the following where you are enqueueing your syles(probably in `functions.php`):

```
if(isset($_GET['style']) && $_GET['style']=='alt'){
  wp_enqueue_script('alternate_style);
else{
  wp_enqueue_script('normal_style);
}
```